# Setup cross-domain tracking for iframe

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

I want to attribute the purchase event and other events made inside an iframe to the source from where the user came from (Ads/UTM) on the parent page.

According to Google (Link below: Manual setup Method), if I initialize Google Analytics 4 (ga4) inside the iframe with the same client_id and session_id as the parent page, it will be considered the same user.

However, when I try this, a new user and session are being created even though the cookie values for _ga and ga are the same for both the parent and the iframe. I have confirmed that these cookie values are the same.

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/10071811?hl=en#zippy=%2Cmanual-setup

Is there something I am missing or doing wrong?